# Uncaught exception - Set is not a function (Lightning)

Tags: lightning

```
formatPhone:function(component, event, helper) {
    var phoneValue = component.find("phoneId");
    phoneValue = Array.isArray(phoneValue) ? phoneValue[0].get("v.value") : phoneValue.get("v.value");

    if(phoneValue.length > 3 && phoneValue.length < 6 && (!phoneValue.includes("(") &&  !phoneValue.includes(")"))){

        phoneValue[0].set("v.value","("+phoneValue.substr(0,3)+") "+phoneValue.substr(3,phoneValue.length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're handling an array return from `component.find()` twice, and also taking its value when you want the element itself.

First, you do this:

```
phoneValue = Array.isArray(phoneValue) ? phoneValue[0].get("v.value") : phoneValue.get("v.value");
```

which gives you the `v.value` property of the first element of `phoneValue`, which you use in the following logic. But then you also do

```
phoneValue[0].set("v.value" ...)
```

while `phoneValue` is now set to the *value* of the first element returned by `component.find()`, not the element itself. You need to hold on to that element value before you call `get("v.value")`, so that you can later call `set()`, and you need to not use array access a second time.

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I tried this. Yet, I receive the same error -
`component.find("phoneId").set("v.value","("+phoneValue.substr(0,3)+") "+phoneValue.substr(3,phoneValue.length)); `

Comment: @Nishanth Perhaps `component.find("phoneId")` returns an Array?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: So you need to use that expression you already have to get the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

After the second line, `phoneValue` is now just a String, not a SecureComponent. I suggest this instead:

```
var phone, phoneCmp = component.find('phoneId');
if(phoneCmp) {  // we have an object?
    if(phoneCmp.length) {  // this is an array
        phoneCmp = phoneCmp[0];
    }
    if(phoneCmp.get) { // this is a component?
        phone = phoneCmp.get('v.value');
        if(phone && phone.match(/^\d{3,}$/)) { // only digits, at least 3?
            phoneCmp.set('v.value', '('+phone.substring(0,3)+')+phone.substring(3));

    }
}
```

Your main problem was that you "forgot" your component reference, so you couldn't call the set method, because you were trying to call that on a String. Always be careful to keep track of what's in your variables.